# cordova-plugin-email-composer will not open the email

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I am writing an app that needs to simply send an email and am having trouble with the most basic function, which should just open a blank email. I have used the plugin https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer#examples but I seem to be making what must be a trivial mistake because it seems so straight forward. Please advise on what the issue might be. Here is the HTML Code:

```html
  <body>
    <h1>Email Sender</h1>
    <div id="userInteract">
    Message: <input type="text" id="userMsg"></input>
    <button onclick="send()">Send</button>
    </div>
    <script>
      function send(){

      cordova.plugins.email.open();

      }
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: you can check for devices that are able to send emails: cordova.plugins.email.isAvailable

Comment: @NamitSingal I get this when I run it in the browser but that should be normal since it should only work on the phone anyway right?

Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not definedsend @ sendEmail.html:21onclick @ sendEmail.html:15

Comment: Can any one help on this as I am facing the same issue